# Does performance of this query can be improved

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a very slow query in MySql server.

I add the query :

```
SELECT  CRR_DT, TOU, SRCE, SINK, NAME, SEASON, SRCESUMCONG, SINKSUMCONG,
        SRCEAVGCONG, SINKAVGCONG, SUMSINKMSRCE, AVGSINKMSRCE,
        HOURCOUNT, TERM, START_DT, END_DT, CTYPE, MW AS MW_AWARD,
        Mark, SCID
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  a.CRR_DT, a.TOU, a.SRCE, a.SINK, a.NAME, a.SEASON, a.SRCESUMCONG,
                a.SINKSUMCONG, a.SRCEAVGCONG, a.SINKAVGCONG, a.SUMSINKMSRCE,
                a.AVGSINKMSRCE, a.HOURCOUNT, b.TERM, b.CTYPE, b.START_DT,
                b.END_DT, b.MW, b.SCID, b.Mark
            FROM  
              ( SELECT  CRR_DT, TOU, SRCE, SINK, NAME, SEASON, SRCESUMCONG, SINKSUMCONG,
                        SRCEAVGCONG, SINKAVGCONG, SUMSINKMSRCE, AVGSINKMSRCE,
                        HOURCOUNT
                    FROM  CRR_CONGCALC
                    WHERE  CRR_DT >= '2015-01'
              ) a
            INNER JOIN  
              ( SELECT  MARKET, TERM, TOU, SRCE, SINK, NAME, SCID, CTYPE, START_DT,
                        END_DT, SUM(MW) AS MW, SUBSTR(MARKET, 1, 3) AS MARK
                    FROM  CRR_INVENTORY
                    WHERE  COPTION = 'OBLIGATION'
                      AND  START_DT >= '2015-01-01'
                      AND  SCID IN ('EAGL' , 'LDES')
                    GROUP BY  MARKET , TOU , SRCE , SINK , NAME , SCID , CTYPE ,
                        START_DT , END_DT
              ) b ON a.NAME = b.NAME
              AND  a.TOU = b.TOU
      ) c
    WHERE  c.CRR_DT BETWEEN SUBSTR(c.START_DT, 1, 7) AND SUBSTR(c.END_DT, 1, 7 )
    ORDER BY  NAME , CRR_DT , TOU ASC
```

Here the result its `Explain plan` generated using [**MysQl Workbrench**](https://www.mysql.fr/products/workbench/)

[image]

I guess that the red block red are dangerous. Can please someone help me to understand this plan? Few hints on what I should check once I have this execution plan.

### edit add TABLES layout

```
CREATE TABLE `CRR_CONGCALC` (
  `CRR_DT` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `TOU` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `SRCE` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `SINK` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `SRCESUMCONG` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SINKSUMCONG` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SRCEAVGCONG` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SINKAVGCONG` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SUMSINKMSRCE` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVGSINKMSRCE` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HOURCOUNT` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SEASON` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NAME` varchar(110) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CRR_DT`,`SRCE`,`SINK`,`TOU`,`HOURCOUNT`),
  KEY `srce_index` (`SRCE`),
  KEY `srcesink` (`SRCE`,`SINK`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `CRR_INVENTORY` (
  `MARKET` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `TERM` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `TOU` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `INVENTORY_DT` date NOT NULL,
  `START_DT` datetime NOT NULL,
  `END_DT` datetime NOT NULL,
  `CRR_ID` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `NSR_INDEX` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `SEGMENT` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `CTYPE` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `CATEGORY` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `COPTION` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `SRCE` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SINK` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MW` decimal(8,4) NOT NULL,
  `SCID` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `SEASON` char(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `NAME` varchar(110) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MARKET`,`INVENTORY_DT`,`CRR_ID`),
  KEY `srcesink` (`SRCE`,`SINK`)
)
```

Comment: I am using MysQl Workbrench.

Comment: could you also paste the sql that generates this query plan as well. Also interested to know what tool visualizes queries like this.

Comment: I would suggest that you ask another question where you include the query  and the table layout.  Then ask if the performance can be improved.

Comment: @agstudy, thanks for pasting the query, but in its current form its barely legible. could you reformat it please. It seems to me there are a couple levels of nested queries, but it would be much easier to tell if the code block was formatted properly.

Comment: @HaleemurAli does it looks better now?

Comment: the nested SELECTs make me cringe. Have you tried creating indexed temp tables with that data and JOIN against them?

Comment: @Timothy can you explain more how I can use temp table here?

Comment: basically you'd create new tables that contain just the results of those SELECT statements so it's a smaller set of data the server has to sift through. Even then, you still want indexes. Your solution is 1) don't do nested SELECTS (there's a place and time, but generally try to avoid) and 2) add indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Brings back memories.  With a database, a "Full Table Scan" means that there is nothing that the database can use to speed up the query, it reads the entire table.  **The rows are stored in a non-sorted order**, so there is no better way to "search" for the employee id you are looking for.

This is bad.  Why?

If you have a table with a bunch of columns:
`first_name, last_name, employee_id, ..., column50` and do a search `where employee_id = 1234`, if you don't have an index on the employee_id column, you're doing a sequential scan.  Even worse if you're doing a `join table2 on table1.employee_id = table2.eid`, because it has to match the employee_id to every record in the join table.

If you create an index, you greatly reduce the scan time to find the matches (or throw away the non-matches) because instead of doing a sequential scan you can search a sorted field.  Much faster.

When you create an index on the employee_id field, you are creating a way to search for employee numbers that is much, much, much faster.  **When you create an index, you are saying "I am going to join based on this field or have a where clause based on this field"**.  This speeds up your query at the cost of a little bit of disk space.

There are all kinds of tricks with indexes, you can create them so they are unique, not unique, composite (contain multiple columns) and all kinds of stuff.  Post your query and we can tell you what you might look at indexing to speed this up.

A good rule of thumb is that you should create an index on your tables on fields that you use in a where clause, join criteria or order by.  Picking the field depends on a few things that are beyond the scope of this discussion, but that should be a start.

Answer (score 2):

- The pattern `FROM ( SELECT... ) JOIN ( SELECT... ) ON ...` does not optimize well.  See if you can go directly from one of the tables, not hide it in a subquery.
- `CRR_CONGCALC` needs `INDEX(CRR_DT)`.  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)
- `CRR_INVENTORY` needs `INDEX(COPTION, START_DT)`.

Please make those changes, then come back for more advice, if needed.

Comment: Thank you. I added tables layout.

Comment: OK, you have the first index, but not (yet) the second one.

Answer (score 2):

According to your explain diagram, there are full table scans happening at each sub-query on `CRR_CONGCALC` and `CRR_INVENTORY`. Then when you join the sub-queries together, another full table scan, and finally, when the result set is ordered, one more full table scan.

A Few tips to improve performance

1. Use fields that are indexed as part of your join statement, where clause, group by clause & order by clause. If this query is used often, consider adding indexes to all relevant columns.
2. **Avoid nested sub-queries with aggregate operations in joins as much as possible. The result-sets returned by the sub-queries are not indexed, joining on it will end up scanning the whole table, rather than just the index.** *The joins in this query could also result in weird and hard to detect fanning out issues, but this isn't a performance issue that you're seeking a solution for*
3. Filter the result set as early as possible (i.e. in all the sub-queries at the inner most layer to minimize the # of rows the database server has to subsequently deal with.
4. Unless the final order by is necessary, avoid it.
5. Use temporary (or materialized) tables to de-nest subqueries. On these tables, you can add indexes, so further joining will be efficient. **This assumes that you have the permissions to create & drop tables on the server**

That said,

Here's how I would refactor your query.

- In generating the inner query `b`, the group by clause does not contain all fields which are not aggregate columns. This is non standard sql, which leads to malformed data. Mysql allows it, and for the love of god I don't know why. It is best to avoid this *trap*.
- The final wrapping query is unnecessary, as the where clause and group by clause can be applied to the unwrapped query.
- This where clause seems fishy to me:

  ```
  c.CRR_DT BETWEEN SUBSTR(c.START_DT, 1, 7) AND SUBSTR(c.END_DT, 1, 7)
  ```

  `START_DT` & `END_DT` are `datetime` or `timestamp` columns being implicitly `cast` as `char`. It would be better to extract the year-month using the function `DATE_FORMAT` as:

  ```
  DATE_FORMAT(<FIELD>, '%Y-%m-01')
  ```

  Even if the where clause you used worked, it would omit records for which `END_DT` and `CRR_DT` fall in the same month. I'm not sure if that is the desired behaviour, but here's a query to illustrate what your boolean expression would evaluate:

  ```
  SELECT CAST('2015-07-05' AS DATETIME) between '2015-07' and '2015-07';
  -- This query returns 0 == False.
  ```

Using [`CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-select.html), first de-nest the sub queries. **Note: as I don't know the data, I'm not sure which indexes need to be unique.** You can delete the tables once the result is consumed.

Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE sub_a (KEY(CRR_DT), KEY(NAME), KEY(TOU), KEY(NAME, TOU)) AS
SELECT CRR_DT,
       TOU,
       SRCE,
       SINK,
       NAME,
       SEASON,
       SRCESUMCONG,
       SINKSUMCONG,
       SRCEAVGCONG,
       SINKAVGCONG,
       SUMSINKMSRCE,
       AVGSINKMSRCE,
       HOURCOUNT
FROM CRR_CONGCALC
WHERE CRR_DT >= '2015-01-01';
```

Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE sub_b (KEY(NAME), KEY(TOU), KEY(NAME, TOU)) AS
SELECT MARKET,
       TERM,
       TOU,
       SRCE,
       SINK,
       NAME,
       SCID,
       CTYPE,
       START_DT,
       END_DT,
       SUM(MW) AS MW_AWARD,
       SUBSTR(MARKET,1,3) AS MARK
 FROM CRR_INVENTORY
 WHERE COPTION = 'OBLIGATION'
   AND START_DT >= '2015-01-01'
   AND SCID IN ('EAGL','LDES')
 GROUP BY MARKET, TERM, TOU, 
          SRCE, SINK, NAME, SCID, 
          CTYPE, START_DT, END_DT, MARK
 -- note the two added columns in the groupby clause.
```

After this, the final query would be simply:

```
SELECT a.CRR_DT, 
       a.TOU, 
       a.SRCE,
       a.SINK, 
       a.NAME, 
       a.SEASON, 
       a.SRCESUMCONG,
       a.SINKSUMCONG, 
       a.SRCEAVGCONG, 
       a.SINKAVGCONG, 
       a.SUMSINKMSRCE,
       a.AVGSINKMSRCE, 
       a.HOURCOUNT, 
       b.TERM, 
       b.CTYPE, 
       b.START_DT,
       b.END_DT,
       b.MW_AWARD,
       b.SCID, 
       b.Mark
FROM sub_a a 
JOIN sub_b b ON a.NAME = b.NAME AND a.TOU = b.TOU
WHERE a.CRR_DT BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(b.START_DT,'%Y-%m-01') 
  AND DATE_FORMAT(b.END_DT,'%Y-%m-01')
ORDER BY NAME,
         CRR_DT,
         TOU;
```

The above where clause follows the same logic used in your query, except, it's not trying to cast to string. However, this WHERE clause may be more appropriate,

```
WHERE sub_a.CRR_DT BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(sub_b.START_DT,'%Y-%m-01') 
      AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(sub_b.END_DT, INTERVAL 1 MONTH),'%Y-%m-01')
```

Finally both `sub_a` & `sub_b` seem to have the fields `SRCE` & `SINK`. Would the result change if you added them to the join. That could further optimize the query (at this point, its fair to say queries) processing time.

By doing the above, we hopefully avoid two full table scans, but I don't have your data set, so I'm only making an educated guess here.

**If its possible to express this logic without using intermediary tables, and directly via joins to the actual underlying tables `CRR_CONGCALC` and `CRR_INVENTORY`, that would be even faster**

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer.Maybe I can replace `CREATE TABLE`  by `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS...`

Comment: yes, you can safely replace `create table` with `create temporary table if not exists`

Comment: Be sure to add `INDEX(name, tou)` to `sub_a` and `sub_b`.

Answer (score 1):

Full table scans operations are not always bad, or necessarily evil. Sometimes, a full scan is the most efficient way to satisfy a query. For example, the query  `SELECT * FROM mytable` requires MySQL to return *every* row in the table and *every* column in each row.  And in this case, using an index would just make more work. It's faster just to do a full scan.

On the other hand, if you're retrieving a couple of rows out of a million, an access plan using a suitable index is very likely to be much faster than a full table scan. Effective use of a index can eliminate vast swaths of rows that would otherwise need to be checked; the index basically tells MySQL that the rows we're looking for cannot be in 99% of the blocks in the table, so those blocks don't need to be checked.

MySQL processes views (including inline views) differently than other databases. MySQL uses the term **derived table** for an inline view. In your query `a`, `b` and `c` are all derived tables. MySQL runs the query to return the rows, and then *materializes* the view into a table. Once that is completed, the outer query can run against the derived table. But as of MySQL 5.5 (and I think 5.6), inline views are *always* materialized as derived tables. And that's a performance killer for large sets. (Some performance improvements are coming in newer versions of MySQL, some automatic indexing.)

Also, predicates in the outer query do *not* get pushed down into the view query. That is, if we run a query like this:

```
  SELECT t.foo 
    FROM mytable t
   WHERE t.foo = 'bar'
```

MySQL can make use of an index with a leading column of `foo` to efficiently locate the rows, even if mytable contains millions of rows. But if we write the query like this:

```
  SELECT t.foo
    FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable) t
   WHERE t.foo = 'bar'
```

We're essentially forcing MySQL to make a copy of `mytable`, running the inline view query, to populate a derived table, containing all rows from mytable. And once that operation is complete, the outer query can run. But now, there's no index on the `foo` column in the derived table. So we're forcing MySQL to do a full scan of the derived table, to look at every row.

If we need an inline view, then relocating the predicate to the inline view query will result in a much smaller derived table.

```
  SELECT t.foo
    FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE foo = 'bar') t
```

With that, MySQL can make use of the index on `foo` to quickly locate the rows, and only those rows are materialized into the derived table. The full scan of the derived table isn't as painful now, because the outer query needs to return *every* row. In this example, it would also be much better to replace that `*` (representing every column) with just the columns we need to return.

---

The resultset you specify could be returned without the unnecessary inline views. A query something like this:

```
        SELECT c.crr_dt
             , c.tou
             , c.srce
             , c.sink
             , c.name
             , c.season
             , c.srcesumcong
             , c.sinksumcong
             , c.srceavgcong
             , c.sinkavgcong
             , c.sumsinkmsrce
             , c.avgsinkmsrce
             , c.hourcount
             , b.term
             , b.start_dt
             , b.end_dt
             , b.ctype
             , b.mw AS mw_award
             , b.scid
             , b.mark
          FROM CRR_CONGCALC c
          JOIN ( SELECT i.market
                      , i.term
                      , i.tou
                      , i.srce
                      , i.sink
                      , i.name
                      , i.scid
                      , i.ctype
                      , i.start_dt
                      , i.end_dt
                      , SUM(i.mw) AS mw
                      , SUBSTR(i.market, 1, 3) AS mark
                   FROM CRR_INVENTORY i
                  WHERE i.coption = 'OBLIGATION'
                    AND i.start_dt >= '2015-01-01'
                    AND i.scid IN ('EAGL','LDES')
                  GROUP
                     BY i.market
                      , i.tou
                      , i.srce
                      , i.sink
                      , i.name
                      , i.scid
                      , i.ctype
                      , i.start_dt
                      , i.end_dt
               ) b
            ON c.name = b.name
           AND c.tou  = b.tou
           AND c.crr_dt >= '2015-01'
           AND c.crr_dt BETWEEN SUBSTR(b.start_dt,1,7) 
                            AND SUBSTR(b.end_dt,1,7)
         ORDER
            BY c.name
             , c.crr_dt
             , c.tou
```

NOTES: If `start_dt` and `end_dt` are defined as `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` columns, then I'd prefer to write the predicate like this:

```
 AND c.crr_dt BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(b.start_dt,'%Y-%m') AND DATE_FORMAT(b.end_dt,'%Y-%m')
```

(I don't think there's any performance to be gained there; that just makes it more clear what we're doing.)

---

In terms of improving performance of that query...

If we're returning a small subset of rows from `CRR_INVENTORY`, based on the predicates:
                      WHERE i.coption = 'OBLIGATION'
                        AND i.start_dt >= '2015-01-01'
                        AND i.scid IN ('EAGL','LDES')

Then MySQL would likely be able to make effective use of an index with leading columns of `(coption,scid,start_dt)`. That's assuming that this represents a relatively small subset of rows from the table. If those predicates are not very selective, if we're really getting 50% or 90% of the rows in the table, the index is likely going to much less effective.

We might be able to get MySQL to make use of an index to satisfy the `GROUP BY` clause, without requiring a sort operation. To get that, we'd need an index with leading columns that match the columns listed in the GROUP BY clause.

The derived table isn't going to have an index on it, so for best peformance of the join operation, we want an index on the other table ) is materialized, then we are going to want a suitable index on the other table `CRR_CONGCALC`. We want the leading columns of that index to be used for the lookup of the matching rows, the predicates:

```
            ON c.name = b.name
           AND c.tou  = b.tou
           AND c.crr_dt >= '2015-01'
           AND c.crr_dt BETWEEN SUBSTR(b.start_dt,1,7) 
                            AND SUBSTR(b.end_dt,1,7)
```

So, we want an index with leading columns of `(name, tou, crr_dt)` to be able to efficiently locate the matching rows.

Comment: Tank for this detailed answer. I really appreciate it. Unfortunately when I try it , it is even slower than the original one ( I lost connection with MySql )).

Comment: I'd be very surprised that MySQL couldn't (or wouldn't) make effective use of a suitable index. The most likely explanation for the slow performance is  that suitable indexes aren't available, especially on the `CRR_CONGCALC table`... **`(name, tou, crr_dt)`**. But also on the `CRR_INVENTORY` table as well. There's a pretty good chance that with appropriate indexes, this query will outperform the query with the nested inline views.